# Buffer to base64 | Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, encoding, base64, buffer

I have a buffer which is being populated with a bunch of base64 strings. I want a way to decode those string and be able to read all of the base64 strings in that buffer.

```
const slugId1 = 'YriU6QbcQj6xtdUUosJTxA==';
const slugId2 = 'Su7Zvq1vRca/teTNfEmfNQ==';
const SLUGID_SIZE = 16;

let buffer = Buffer.alloc(SLUGID_SIZE * 2);

buffer.write(slugId1, 0, SLUGID_SIZE, 'base64');
buffer.write(slugId2, SLUGID_SIZE, SLUGID_SIZE, 'base64');

console.log(buffer.toString('base64', 0, SLUGID_SIZE));
console.log(buffer.toString('base64', SLUGID_SIZE, SLUGID_SIZE));
```

What I'm getting:

```
YriU6QbcQj6xtdUUosJTxA==
```

What I expect to get:

```
YriU6QbcQj6xtdUUosJTxA==
Su7Zvq1vRca/teTNfEmfNQ==
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `buffer.toString` 2nd and 3rd parameter are `start` and `end` - given you give the same value for start and end, the result is of course zero length

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
const slugId1 = 'YriU6QbcQj6xtdUUosJTxA==';
const slugId2 = 'Su7Zvq1vRca/teTNfEmfNQ==';
const SLUGID_SIZE = 16;

let buffer = Buffer.alloc(SLUGID_SIZE * 2);

buffer.write(slugId1, 0, SLUGID_SIZE, 'base64');
buffer.write(slugId2, SLUGID_SIZE, SLUGID_SIZE, 'base64');

console.log(buffer.toString('base64', 0, SLUGID_SIZE));
console.log(buffer.toString('base64', SLUGID_SIZE, SLUGID_SIZE * 2));
```

buffer.toString() - third argument is not length, it is end offset.

Comment: `buffer.write() - third argument is not length, it is end offset` - no, for write it is a length - see [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_write_string_offset_length_encoding) - you could actually do `buffer.write(slugId2, SLUGID_SIZE, 'base64');` - because the length defaults to buffer.length - offset - in this case, it would be SLUGID_SIZE

Comment: Yup, that did it. Thanks for the quick response!